# How does interp1d in scipy handle ties

Tags: python, scipy

The documentation for `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` is silent on what happens when there are ties in the `x` argument. My experimenting suggests that it returns the rightmost one when that exact x value is requested and uses the closest one when interpolating:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
temp = interp1d([0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4])
temp(0.5)  # 1.5
temp(1)  # 3.0
temp(1.5)  # 3.5
```

Is this guaranteed by the design of the interpolator?

Comment: Are you limiting the question to the default 'linear' kind?

Comment: At the moment, I am only interested in the linear algorithms, but knowing about the behavior the the alternatives may be useful for the future.

Answer (score 1):

`interp1d` is defined in `scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py`.  For the default 'linear' kind it appears to take two alternatives.

```
            # Check if we can delegate to numpy.interp (2x-10x faster).
            if (not np.issubdtype(self.y.dtype, np.complexfloating) and
               self.y.ndim == 1 and
               not _do_extrapolate(fill_value)):
                self._call = self.__class__._call_linear_np
            else:
                self._call = self.__class__._call_linear
```

The `call_linear_np` does:

```
np.interp(x_new, self.x, self.y)
```

The function calls compiled code.  The docs talk about expecting `xp` to be increasing, but it does not actually check this.

```
def _call_linear(self, x_new):
```

appears to be all Python, which you can study.

What you describe is what I'd expect for linear interpolation.  But keep in mind that this code operates with floats, and 'exact equality' is not guaranteed with floats.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not guaranteed.

Behavior of an interpolator when there are ties in `x` values is undefined, and may change between scipy versions. (Also the interpolation kind and where in the arrays are the ties).